# Trouble with installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1

I work with Windows 8.1 and today I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside it, but now I can't set the boot menu to display both OS.

When I boot the system it normally loads Windows 8.1 without opening the boot menu.

I created a boot USB with Yumi. When booting with Yumi and selecting "boot from hard disk", Ubuntu turned on.

My drives:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4OqK.png]

My laptop is a Fujitsu Lifebook AH532/G52 and the BIOS is a Phoenix v1.10

Answer (score 0):

1. In Windows, download and install [Easy BCD](https://neosmart.net/Download/Register/1).
2. Open Easy BCD.
3. Create a new boot entry, name it Ubuntu and assign it to your corresponding EXT3 partition.
4. Reboot your computer to see if your newly created Ubuntu entry works.

Comment: i do this, but i get "Error opening BCD registery"

Comment: Did you run Easy BCD with administrative right?

Comment: yes i do. but don't work

Comment: Is this an EFI machine? Is your Windows 64 bit or 32 bit? Is Ubuntu 64 bit?

Comment: Both OS are 64 bit & i have EFI partition (http://i.stack.imgur.com/w4OqK.png).

Comment: Can you boot into your UEFI and turn on BIOS compatibility mode?

Comment: My BIOS don't has any menu for this work. my laptop is "Fujitsu Lifebook AH532/G52" my BISO is phoenix v1.10

Comment: Is there any settings named secure boot or disable UEFI in your BIOS?

Comment: no :(((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: Try to set an admin password in BIOS then.  Source: http://www.linlap.com/fujitsu_lifebook_ah532

Comment: i set supervisor password but don't work that solution.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I had a dual boot but if I remember correctly, you need to have Ubuntu's `/boot` partition ahead of Windows'.

During boot first found boot script is used.

So I see that you have an used partition before `NFTS` that is formatted as `other`.

Format that as `ext4` , give it `boot flag`, and make mount point `/boot`.